# Which Java Download Do I Need?

Tags: windows-vista, java

Does anybody know which of these downloads I should choose when updating Java?

- Windows x86 Online 0.85 MB    jre-7u6-windows-i586-iftw.exe
- Windows x86 Offline 29.73 MB    jre-7u6-windows-i586.exe
- Windows x64 31.18 MB    jre-7u6-windows-x64.exe

I have Windows Vista but I don't know if it is 64 or 32-bit (x86)?

Comment: there's no "84" bit

Answer (score 1):

Check My Computer -> Properties whether you have either 32 or 64 bit.

If 32 -> x86 (either online or offline, its the same)
If 64 -> x64, but 32bit is also compatible.

Comment: This is applicable to your whole computer. So everty time you have to choose between either 32 or 64 bit software you must choose the 32 version.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SecurAble](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) to find out if you have a 64-bit or a 32-bit system(check the maximum bit length field)

[image]

- If it says 64-bit, you can use Windows x64 *or* the Windows x86 version
- If it says 32-bit, you *must* install the Windows x86 version

The "Online" part in the filename indicates that it's a bootstrap installer, and the actual installer will be further downloaded. The "offline" indicates that it's the full installer and you can use it to install, even if there's no Internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Even if in your post you just write about JRE, it even depends if you want to update your JRE (Java Runtime Environment), or your JDK (Java Development Kit).

The latter (**JDK**) is needed if you want to compile (and run) your own pieces of java code.

The former (**JRE**) is required (and included in the JDK of course) if you just want to run java.

Furthermore, if you have a running copy of JRE in your system it will update itself with a coherent version.